High school applications of Hilbert's Nullstellsatz.
I am looking for non-trivial problems that can be understood by high-schoolers and can be solved by Hilbert's Nullstellensatz. It is ok if the solution is not at a high school level, only the problem needs to be.
Can you help me or point me to a reference?
Note: I have cross posted this on reddit too.
